# How do we "hide" events when generating code from MATLAB?

Tags: c++, matlab, code-generation

We're currently the codegen tool to generate C/C++ code from MATLAB .m scripts. However, when we try to generate code from pages that contain events, we get an error complaining that MATLAB cannot handle the events.

Currently our workaround is to '%' comment out the events (which the C code doesn't depend on), generate the code and uncomment the events afterwards, but this is tedious and error-prone.

Within actual code-blocks, we can use `if (coder.target('MATLAB'))` to handle this kind of issue, is there an equivalent technique for hiding the fact that we have events defined?

Comment: I do not think there is a way to skip it with coder.target. One possible way is to use hierarchy of classes with the base class without events and child class events. When you want to generate code you would use the base class. Still you may need to change the code which creates the class in this case.

Comment: @Navan: That was my suspicion, it's just potentially an extensive (if theoretically trivial) re-write of existing code, as well as requiring that structure to be maintained going forward, and I was hoping for other options.